# Avoid passing generic type parameter of class extending generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, parameter-passing

I have an abstract class Creature that takes a generic type argument, extended by two other classes Human and Spider. Each subclass defines the generic type of its parent.

I am stuck with how to pass a subclass as a reference of parent class to a method.

```
public interface IDamagable
{
    void OnSimpleHit();
}

public interface IStabAble : IDamagable
{
    void OnKnifeStab();
}

public interface ISlapAble : IDamagable
{
    void OnSlap();
}

public abstract class Creature<T> where T : IDamagable
{
    public abstract void Init(T damageListener);
}

public abstract class Human : Creature<ISlapAble>
{

}

public abstract class Spider : Creature<IStabAble>
{

}

public class MainClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        List<Spider> spiderList = new List<Spider>();
        List<Human> humanList = new List<Human>();

        PrintList<IDamagable>(spiderList); // Argument `#1' cannot convert
        //`System.Collections.Generic.List<newAd.B_A_A>' expression 
        //to type `System.Collections.Generic.List<newAd.A_A<newAd.I_B>>'
    }

    protected void PrintList<T>(List<Creature<T>> list)
    {

    }
}
```

This doesnt throw error if PrintList took 2 generic arguments

```
protected void PrintList<T,U>(List<T> list) where T : Creature<U> where U : IDamagable
    {

    }
```

But then I don't want to pass U again, as T was already constructed with U as type parameter, e.g Spider already defined Creature to take type parameter of IStabAble.

So basically, I'm stuck with how to write the method such that it caters both Spider and Human with minimal number of generic parameters.
Thanks

Comment: You should consider renaming your classes to something understandable that makes the relationships in your class hierarchy easy to follow. You are not going to get much help if simply understanding your code is a guaranteed headache.

Comment: Try changing the signature of the `PrintList` method to `void PrintList<T>(IEnumerable<A_A<T>> list) where T : I_A`

Comment: Renamed the classes and interfaces, etc
@YacoubMassad I don't understand how changing list to IEnumerable changes anything

Comment: Could you rename everithing on the text to? Also in the comented code

Comment: @Farhan, `PrintList` seems to want to print the list, i.e., it requires read-only forward-only access to the list. If this is all what you want, then an `IEnumerable<T>` would work.

Comment: @Farhan, unlike `List<T>`, the generic type parameter in `IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @YacoubMassad Still, I don't see how it could solve the issue . Tried it, still the same error.

Comment: @Farhan, do you require methods in the list that are not part of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface? For example, do you want to access items in the list by index? Or add items to the list?

Comment: Oh, that. Yes, it could be substituted with IEnumerable in the given situation. All I meant was that its deviating from the issue at hand.

Comment: Did you change it to IEnumerable? as @YacoubMassad suggested? He suggested it because IEnumerable(Of T) supports covariance.

Comment: The compiler does not allow you to use a `List` in this case, because what happens if the list is of type `T1 : Creature<IDamagable>` and you try to add an item of type `T2 : Creature<IDamagable>`?

Comment: That was some useful information. Thanks!
As for IEnumerable, yes I converted List to IEnumerable. Still no luck!
Changed spider list to this :
    `IEnumerable<Spider> spiderList = new List<Spider>();`
And changed PrintList to this :
    `protected void PrintList<T>(IEnumerable<Creature<T>> list) where T : IDamagable`

Still the same error :
Argument `#1' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Spider>' expression to type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Creature<IDamagable>>'

Comment: You are missing a type parameter constraint on `PrintList`. The whole signature of the method should be `void PrintList<T>(IEnumerable<Creature<T>> list) where T: IDamagable`.

Comment: Also you are passing the incorrect type parameter when you invoke. You should use `PrintList<IStabAble>(spiderList);` or `PrintList(spiderList);` ( the compiler automatically infers T)

Comment: Compiler apparently isn't able to infer it automatically. I'm using .Net 2.0.
With the first option, I get the same error :
Argument `#1' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Spider>' expression to type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Creature<IStabAble>>'

Comment: Aha. OK. The problem is that in .NET 2.0 there are no covariant type parameters.

Comment: Damn. I have no other option but to use .Net 2.0 :( Any suggestion on how it could be achieved with .Net 2? Something like, if I could get the `T` from concrete object of Spider class statically?
What then could be the minimal number of parameters to use in PrintList method? I have to go with 2 generic parameters in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `PrintList` only requires read-only forward-only access to the list.

The solution is to make the `PrintList` method accept an `IEnumerable<Creature<T>>` like this:

```
void PrintList<T>(IEnumerable<Creature<T>> list) where T: IDamagable
{
    //...
}
```

And call it like this:

```
PrintList(spiderList);
```

Because the generic type parameter `T` in `IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this will work.

In your special case, because you are using .NET 2.0 (which does not support covariant type parameters) this solution will not work. Here is a workaround:

Create a `Cast` method that can convert between enumerables with different item types like this (in .NET 3.5, we already have such method as an extension method):

```
public static IEnumerable<U> Cast<T, U>(IEnumerable<T> source) where T : U
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
PrintList(Cast<Spider, Creature<IStabAble>>(spiderList));
```

Comment: So the minimal number of generic types I have to use is 2. I do intend to use random list index, however, just for the final bit of clarification, the variation I proposed `protected void PrintList<T,U>(List<T> list) where T : Creature<U> where U : IDamagable
    {
    }` is also equally fine in terms of efficiency? No type casting required so...?

Comment: My version of `PrintList` has a single type parameter. But before you invoke it you have to cast the enumerable to the correct type. Your version is a bit more efficient because it does not involve casting. If you need to access items by index, then you have the use a `List` and thus you need to have the two parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much!